# How to divide the cost by different places(reasonable price)?

Tags: math, calculator

I want to divide the cost by different places.

The total rent fee is $8,000 and it include warehouse and the office.
The price per sq ft of warehouse should be cheaper than the office.
The sq ft of warehouse is 7,000 and the sq ft of the office is 3,000.

The price rate I want to get is 6(the office) and 4(the warehouse).
so (7000 * warehouse rate) + (3000 * Office rate) = $8,000.

I have been using excel to calculate this but I guess I need to study math more.

Comment: Hm, this problem has about two dozens solutions The following pairs for (WH rate, Office rate) will satisfy it: `($0.17, $2.27), ($0.2, $2.2), ($0.5, $1.5). ($0.77, $0.87). and some more. Yes, you have to study math more.

Comment: How to get these prices without input every number?
Also, the ratio of price I want is 6(the office) and 4(the warehouse).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's denote warehouse price as `x` and office price as `y`
Then we have a system of two equations.

```
7 * x + 3 * y = 8
x / y = 2/3
```

From the second equation  `y = 3/2 *x`. substituting this to the first equation we have.

```
7 * x + (3 * 3 * y)/2 = 7 * x + 9/2 * x = (7 + 9/2 *x ) = 8
```

Multiplying both parts of the equation by `2`

```
(14 + 9) * x = 25 * x = 16
```

So `x = 16/25 = 0.64` and `y = (8 - 7 *x ) / 3 = 1.17333(3)` 
You will have to round office space price

Comment: `14 + 9 = 23` ;-)